# Magento 1.5 Redirect Issue on Firefox and IE

Tags: magento, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have recently changed the name of one of the categories and created a permanent redirect url  for it. But the problem is when I try to navigate to that category it gives a redirect error on firefox and IE.

If I use Safari or Chrome, it works fine. but when I use IE it just refreshes the page and when I use Firefox, I  get this error 
"The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. I have cookies enabled. what can be the problem

Has anyone got same sort of issue before and if anyone has found a solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove all the cookies then restart your browser?

This happens to me right now, viewing the site that I'm currently working and then the error popped out. I tried viewing it on my chrome and it was fine. So I tried to remove all the cookies and restarted my browser and it was all fine.